# How to Figure Which Repo is bad?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I am trying to install a package, and it complains a repository is bad but without telling me which one:

```
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-11-gcc-c++.x86_64
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | 6.3 kB  00:00:00     
 * base: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * elrepo: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * epel: download.nus.edu.sg
 * extras: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * updates: mirror-hk.koddos.net
base                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
centos-sclo-rh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
centos-sclo-sclo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
elrepo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

disk I/O error
```

Is there an easy way to figure out which repository is bad?

Enabled repositories:

```
$ yum repolist enabled
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * elrepo: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * epel: download.nus.edu.sg
 * extras: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * updates: mirror-hk.koddos.net
repo id                                                                                                                                                                                           repo name                                                                                                                                                                                                                        status
base/7/x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                     CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                                                                                                                                                  10,072
centos-sclo-rh/x86_64                                                                                                                                                                             CentOS-7 - SCLo rh                                                                                                                                                                                                                8,166
centos-sclo-sclo/x86_64                                                                                                                                                                           CentOS-7 - SCLo sclo                                                                                                                                                                                                                816
elrepo                                                                                                                                                                                            ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Repository - el7                                                                                                                                                                              148
epel/x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                   13,730
extras/7/x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                   CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                                                                                                                                                   515
google-chrome                                                                                                                                                                                     google-chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                         3
updates/7/x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                  CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                                                                                                                                                4,538
repolist: 37,988
```

Here is the output of `sudo yum update`:

```
$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | 8.9 kB  00:00:00     
 * base: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * elrepo: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * epel: hkg.mirror.rackspace.com
 * extras: mirror-hk.koddos.net
 * updates: mirror-hk.koddos.net
base                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
centos-sclo-rh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
centos-sclo-sclo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
elrepo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | 4.7 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
(1/3): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 1.0 MB  00:00:00     
(2/3): google-chrome/primary                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | 1.8 kB  00:00:00     
(3/3): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 7.0 MB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        3/3


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

disk I/O error
```

Comment: And the `disk I/O error` at the bottom doesn't say anything to you? :-)

Comment: @DanilaVershinin I thought it did but it actually doesn't -- I tried to manually turn off all repos except google-chrome repo to update chrome and it worked and so it meant there is no disk error actually?

Comment: I would recommend checking the SMART status of your disks, e.g. `smartctl -a /dev/sda` as root. Better safe than sorry. The `Disk I/O error` might have been a result of a disk routinely detecting a failing block and replacing it with a spare on next write, but you might want to keep an eye of how much reserve blocks your disk has. If the reserve starts dwindling rapidly (days/hours), it is time to backup everything important ASAP. But if the "used reserved block count" parameter seems essentially stable, it might have been just a single event.

Comment: @telcoM thanks for the tips, I have 3 physical devices (1 not in-use but connected and recognized by OS).  Running `smartctl -a` on all 3.  Only the one not in-use has errors.  The other 2 are clean.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `sudo yum update` it should specify the failing repo, which you can then remove via editing the repolist or approach in any of the ways that yum has descried to you in your output described above.

Comment: Added the output of `sudo yum update`.  It is still not obvious to me which repo is bad.